# Code doesn't work when referencing to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro in which, when I press one button in a workbook, the code is executed on another workbook. The is already working if I execute it from a unique workbook, but I can’t make it work with the button from an external workbook and I am not sure when and how to reference correctly.

This is the code, where I try to insert a row at the top, insert the Column function and drag it until the end:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastColumn As Integer
Dim rng_source As Range
Dim rng_Destination As Range
Dim l_SourceRows As Long

Set ws = Workbooks("TEST")

ws.Activate

 ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"


 ' Insert row and formula

  ws.Worksheets("LV").Activate
    ws.Sheets("LV").Rows("1:1").Select
     Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
       ws.Sheets("LV").Range("A1").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COLUMN(C)"

' Drag formula until last column

    Set rng_source = ws.Sheets("LV").Range("A1")
       l_SourceRows = rng_source.Rows.Count
         lastColumn = ws.Sheets("LV").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rng_Destination = ws.Sheets("LV").Range(rng_source.Cells(1), Cells(rng_source.Cells(1), lastColumn))
       rng_source.AutoFill Destination:=rng_Destination, Type:=xlFillDefault


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add the file extension to the external workbook name (e.g. "TEST.xlsx")

Comment: Still doesn't work with this method. It stops working when I try to drag the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leaving the rest of your code alone for now, what the following does is, set "ws" to mean the workbook named "TEST" (it needs to be already open, I think). You then activate it and give what ever sheet you are on the name "Sheet1". After that you activate the worksheet "LV" in that "TEST" worksheet. I am not sure what you are trying to do with those steps?

```
Set ws = Workbooks("TEST")

ws.Activate

 ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"

 ' Insert row and formula

  ws.Worksheets("LV").Activate
    ws.Sheets("LV").Rows("1:1").Select
```

I assume you want to press a button, open another sheet and then do your code on that sheet? How about you simply copy your whole code, make a new sub and then change the set line to something that opens the other workbook? Like so Maybe:

```
Sub test()

Dim lastColumn As Integer
Dim rng_source As Range
Dim rng_Destination As Range

'Filepath of the file in some cell on the workbook (Pick one)
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfTheSheet").Range("B2").Value

'Filepath of the file hard coded in here, simply copy the path and name (Pick one)
    FilePath = "C:\Users\TheMan\Desktop\Test.xlsx"

'Open the file
    Set ws = Workbooks.Open(FilePath, ReadOnly:=False)

'Now you do everything with the other workbook that you did to "ws" before.
'Not sure you really need/want this.
    ws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"


'Insert row and formula
    ws.Worksheets("LV").Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ws.Worksheets("LV").Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COLUMN(C)"

' Drag formula until last column
    lastColumn = ws.Worksheets("LV").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rng_source = ws.Sheets("LV").Range("A1")
    Set rng_Destination = ws.Sheets("LV").Range(rng_source.Cells(1), Cells(rng_source.Cells(1), lastColumn))

    rng_source.AutoFill Destination:=rng_Destination, Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

To be honest I dont quite understand what you are trying to do with your code. I`m using a German Excel tho and for me, the formula "=COLUMN(C)" basically just numbers the first row. Also you Set the Range("A1") and then ask for the row of that range. Why? its always 1 and never gets used. But if for some other reason you really need to drag it, see the edited code.

Comment: I can open the workbook with "Workbooks.Open", but it appears error "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" in the part of "Insert row and formula". Should I introduce something else to run the code? I don't know if "Rows("1:1").Select" should be referenced.

Comment: @Jorge Hey, I'm unsure of what you need done but this code now inserts a a row at the top. Puts your "=COLUMN(C)" in there and then drags in to the last column of row 2. If thats what you want, then this should not throw any errors, at least it doesnt for me. I kept most of your code and just cleaned it up a little. Hope it wasn`t too much.

Comment: I don't know why I get the same error in "Set rng_Destination" (Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error). I think it is correctly referenced with your code. Any idea? Is there any method for which I don't have to reference each line in the code with the "ws."?

Comment: I add, would it be necessary to introduce the two FilePath?

Comment: Hey, no you dont have to have both. Just pick the kind you like. Either code the file path in the module or store it somewhere in a workbook. As to your run-time error: does your other workbook have an "LV" sheet? As I sad, the code has lots of stuff that seems unnecessary but I didnt know what else you are doing. Especially the activation of the new workbook and then renaming of which ever sheet is selected. But since that was present in your code I left it in. Your error means that something is not referenced correctly. Yes, you can use the "with" command to avoid writing ws. all the time.

Comment: I introduced the code in the Module instead of the Sheet and started to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: one last question: ¿How could I use the "with" in order to avoid writing ws. all the time?

Comment: I tried to not putting "ws."and it works. Will there be problems in the future?

Comment: well it works without it because you activate that workbook before. So when, after activating the workbook, you ask it to do something with any sheet, it assumes you mean the activated workbook. I do not like omitting which workbook I am referencing when I have a macro that opens another workbook. Also if you have a long macro that takes a while and you program for other people, they might click into another sheet and wierd things start to happen. so giving a full reference of workbook.worksheet.range.DoStuff is my preference, I know others disagree.